# Java regex to replace numeric values with quotes numeric values

Tags: java, regex

Can someone please help with regex for replacing all integers and doubles with in a given String with single quotes :
Key1=a,Key2=2,Key3=999.6,Key4=8888,Key5=true

with this :
Key1=a,Key2='2',Key3='999.6',Key4='8888',Key5=true

I would like to use regex group capturing rules to replace all numeric string startng after = and replace with ''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a look arounds each end:

```
String quoted = str.replaceAll("(?<==)\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(?=,|$)", "'$0'");
```

The entire match, which is group 0, is the number to be replaced by quotes around group 0.

The match starts with a look behind for an equals and ends with a look ahead for a comma or end of input.

Answer (score 1):

You may try a regex replace all approach here:

```java
String input = "Key1=a,Key2=2,Key3=999.6,Key4=8888,Key5=true";
String output = input.replaceAll("([^,]+)=(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)", "$1='$2'");
System.out.println(output);  // Key1=a,Key2='2',Key3='999.6',Key4='8888',Key5=true
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used:

```regex
([^,]+)             match and capture the key in $1
=                   match =
(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)  match and capture an integer or float number in $2
```

Then, we replace with `$1='$2'`, quoting the number value.